# Remove or Active a certain state when clicking on a div element with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

the past few days I submitted a question about a pagination (how to add and remove an active state in css using pure JavaScript), And I got a great answer. And some what in the same problem i m having an issue removing an active state only this time when clicking on another div.

```
let questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question__container'),
questionBar = document.querySelectorAll('#bar'),
questionClose = document.querySelectorAll('.paragraph__close'),
answers = document.querySelectorAll('.answers__container');

/* activeBar / activeAnswer */

function resetQuestions() {
    for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        questionBar[i].classList.remove('activeBar');
        answers[i].classList.remove('activeAnswer');
    }
}

function addActiveAnswer() {
    for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        questions[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            resetQuestions();
            questionBar[i].classList.add('activeBar');
            answers[i].classList.add('activeAnswer');

            questionClose[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                resetQuestions();
            });
        });
    }
}
addActiveAnswer();
```

I m trying to build whats called a Q&A page, when a user clicks over a question, an answer fades in underneath, But when clicking the closing div element, the `resetQuestions();` doesn't get executed.

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Comment: Are your questions / answers generated dynamically?

Comment: Jquery addClass(), removeClass(), and hasClass() might be easier to use.

Comment: @ObsidianAge no they are thems selfs div elements, one on top another

Comment: @Zapp In this project/website i m trying to avoid Jquery to the max, because i m still in the learning process and i m trying to grasp on the vanilla JavaScript first .